# React Native - I can't seem to get Axios and AsyncStorage to work together in Android, but the code works on iOS?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, asyncstorage

checkState = async() =>  {

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');
  if (value !== null) {
    this.setState({accessToken: value});
  }
}
catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
  this.setState({accessToken: ''});
}
var that = this;
if(this.state.accessToken) {
  axios.get(apicallurl, 
  {headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + that.state.accessToken,
     Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
  }}) 
  .then(response => {
      this.setState({userData: response.data.data[0]});
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      that.setState({accessToken: ''});
    });
}
```

};

This is the function that is being called in ComponentDidMount. I need to check whether the user is logged in or not when accessing this component. I get the value of the accessToken. It goes in the first if statement where it checks if there is an access token or not.

The problem is I don't get a response, but I catch the error. The same code works on iOS and it even works on Android if the Remote JS Debugging is turned on. However if Remote JS Debugging is off, it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where does the error come from in `async storage` catch or `axios` catch? and what is the default value of `accessToken` in the constructor or its initial state?

Comment: It comes from the Axios catch. The default value of accessToken is an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with how you use setState,

From React docs,

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to
>   reflect the new value immediately after calling setState.

Hence accessing `this.state.accessToken` immediately after `this.setState({accessToken: value})` could give you old values.

To solve this,

`const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('access');`

Use this `value` inside the function and `setState` ones after axios response.

ex,instead of `if(this.state.accessToken)` use `if(value)`

> TIP: Don't store a value in `state` when you don't use it in render
>   view. Anyways, you're not going to show accessToken in any view hence,
>   best not to store in any state. Better store it in local or class
>   variable its more than enough.

There are also other ways of solving this problem, but the above is the best for your case. Read React docs for more information.

Check and tell if this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion! However even after that I'm still stuck. Funny thing is the value is stored properly and I can see it in the axios catch. I've narrowed it down to this line of code in index.js which allows me to see network requests in the debugger.

GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest = GLOBAL.originalXMLHttpRequest || GLOBAL.XMLHttpRequest;

After I removed this line even if the debugger is turned on, it still cannot make the api call. But with this line of code if the debugger is turned on, the api call passes and I get a response. With the debugger off, the call fails.